# Check values between set range

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have text inputed by my user for example GSM=-73dBm, each time a user enters a piece of text it will always have the same letters and equals sign the only thing that will change is the number and if it is positive or negative. With each range of values the result changes for example -1 to -70 is bad, 0 to 50 is good and 51 to 100 is excellent. The only way i can think of doing this is listed each value the user could enter. Like below.

```
if ([myTextField.text isEqual:@"GSM=-73dBm"]) {
                                    myTextField.text = @"bad";
                                } else if {
                                    etc..}
```

There must be an easier way to do check this.

Comment: Why does your user have to input "GSM=" and "dBm" when you don't even parse it?  Why aren't you putting that static text either side of text field and just getting her to input numeric values, which can be validated on the fly?  You don't like your users do you.

Comment: @trojanfoe yes i hate them. This project is more of a in house application and we have to paste in a huge piece of text and put it into relevant places in the application so why we have to paste GSM= and dBm was not up to me.

Comment: Given all your questions around basically the same app, I wonder if it wouldn't be easier to ask a programmer to build that app within an hour or so.

Comment: @Eiko i don't see whats wrong with asking questions and understanding with other peoples help to learn. But fair enough

Comment: @vype Nothing wrong with asking questions. But reading a basic introduction to programming, and then working through the guides that Apple provides, will give you a much more solid foundation than piling up hacks for micro-issues. As soon as have built up a basic understanding of programming (and the concepts of iOS programming), many questions will just clear up themselves. And for those that still come up, it will be much easier to help and explain.

Comment: @Eiko Thank you for the advice and ill be sure to take it on and carry on learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString* target = @"GSM=-73dBm";
NSScanner* sc = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:target];
[sc scanUpToString:@"=" intoString:nil];
[sc scanString:@"=" intoString:nil];
NSInteger i;
[sc scanInteger:&i];
```

Now `i` is the number `-73` and you can just do a couple of tests to see what range it's in.

Comment: thank you for the help could you explain a bit further on how i would use this?

Comment: `if (i < 0) ...` and so on

Answer (score 1):

So you can filter out all non numerical values like this.

```
NSString *stringToFilter = @"GSM=-73dBm";


NSMutableString *targetString = [NSMutableString string];


//these are characters that you want to keep, so numbers and negative sign
NSCharacterSet *required = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-0123456789"];


for(int i = 0; i < [stringToFilter length]; i++)
{
    unichar curChar = [stringToFilter characterAtIndex:i];
    if([required characterIsMember:curChar])
    {
        [targetString appendFormat:@"%C", curChar];
    }
}

//convert string to int value
int yourNumber = targetString.intValue;
NSLog(@"%d",yourNumber);
```

This will print "-73". 
Then from here you could if else and check if values are contained in a certain range.

Comment: But GSM=-73dBm can be anything when the user types it in it could be GSM=-89dBm everything but the numbers and "-" stay the same each time its entered.

Comment: well then in that case then it would return -89? I don' think you understand

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the number with regular expression

```
NSString *string = @"GSM=-73dBm";
NSString *pattern = @"-?\\d+";
NSError *error;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:nil error:&error];
if (!error) {
   NSRange result = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:string options: nil range: NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
   NSInteger number = [[string substringWithRange:result] integerValue];
   NSLog(@"%ld", number);
} else {
   NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

The pattern:

- `-?` An optional minus sign, if there could also be a plus sign, use `[+-]?`
- `\\d+` One or more numeric characters